# Remove all words from a file except certain words

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, regular-expression

I have a file which represent a list of SQLs where caluses.
I want to remove everything that is not the columns names, `and`, `or` and `where`(case insensitive). In addition if it can also remove new lines between each `where` it would be perfect.

For example:

```
[/home]$ cat file.txt
wheRe (a='asd') ANd t.b='esd'
WHERE B = 'xcz' or c in ('asd , 'asd')
WHEre C='zxc'
 and t.a    = 'asd'

#running the commadn will generate:
[/home]$ remove_evreything_except "a b c and or where"
where a and b
where b or c
where c and a
```

**UPDATE**

Dirty version;
`grep -o -i -E "where|and|or|\(|\)|[ |\.|(|\"][a|b|c][\"| |=]"  file.txt | tr '[:lower:]' '[:upper:]'| sed 's/ //g' | tr '\n' ' ' |sed 's/[\.||=|\"]//g' | sed 's/WHERE/\nWHERE/g' | sed 's/( /(/g' | sed 's/ )/)/g' | sed 's/()//g'`

Comment: This would probably require an SQL parser.

Comment: I think bash would be simpler :) working on one now

Comment: Do you *always* have just `where columnX and/or columnY` ? Otherwise it will be indeed difficult...

Comment: You need a proper sql parser, otherwise how do you distinguish an `a` as a variable from `a` as a part of the string `'asd'`?

Comment: You are right, my dirty version assume the column would be on the left. That's not good.

Comment: `'asd'`  can be distinguished  with `grep -w`, but `'a'` can not.

Comment: Rememver that `'a'` is just and example. Column names are different and vary from table to table..

Comment: BTW with real column names the above code should work fine as every bind used with `:`

Comment: Little less, but still dirty: `{ IFS=$'\n'; exclude=(a b c and or where); grep -Fwio "${exclude[*]}" file  | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]' | paste -d ' '  - - - -; }`

Comment: If you're happy with this, I'd add as an answer, but somehow I don't like it much for the already mentioned reasons ...